# Can't pass database URL to imdbpy2sql.py script

Tags: python, imdbpy

Whether I'm running imdbpy2sql.py or s32cinemagoer.py the same error occurs:

```
python3 s32cinemagoer.py /home/username/frozendata 'mysql://imdb:imdb@localhost/imdb'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s32cinemagoer.py", line 197, in <module>
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_uri, encoding='utf-8', echo=False)

  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 680, in create_engine
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'encoding' sent to create_engine(), using configuration MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of component
```

I've checked SQLAlchemy [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) on create_engine() function, but still don't get what's the issue with the argumetns I am passing in. create_engine function takes several arguments (e.g.engine = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@hostname/dbname", encoding='latin1', echo=True) including "encoding" argument.

Here is what [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#charset-selection) says about legacy utf-8 encoding in MySQL:

> The encoding used for Unicode has traditionally been 'utf8'. However,
> for MySQL versions 5.5.3 and MariaDB 5.5 on forward, a new
> MySQL-specific encoding 'utf8mb4' has been introduced, and as of MySQL
> 8.0 a warning is emitted by the server if plain utf8 is specified within any server-side directives, replaced with utf8mb3. The
> rationale for this new encoding is due to the fact that MySQL’s legacy
> utf-8 encoding only supports codepoints up to three bytes instead of
> four. Therefore, when communicating with a MySQL or MariaDB database
> that includes codepoints more than three bytes in size, this new
> charset is preferred, if supported by both the database as well as the
> client DBAPI.

[Here is](https://github.com/cinemagoer/cinemagoer/blob/master/imdb/parser/sql/alchemyadapter.py#L438) the set_connection() function from cinemagoer package that probably passes wrong encoding:

```
def setConnection(uri, tables, encoding='utf8', debug=False):
    """Set connection for every table."""
    params = {'encoding': encoding}
    # FIXME: why on earth MySQL requires an additional parameter,
    #        is well beyond my understanding...
    if uri.startswith('mysql'):
        if '?' in uri:
            uri += '&'
        else:
            uri += '?'
        uri += 'charset=%s' % encoding
```

I am now trying to run script with SQLAlchemy 1.3, as [suggested here](https://github.com/cinemagoer/cinemagoer/issues/454) and PyMySQL adapter (otherwise I get [No module named 'MySQLdb' error](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8535)), but it doesn`t seem to work either, same issue occurs.

- Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- Python 3.8.10
- cinemagoer 2023.5.1
- SQLAlchemy 1.3/2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this? just an example, passing encoding directly to db uri

```
def setConnection(uri, tables, encoding='utf8', debug=False):
    """Set connection for every table."""
    # FIXME: why on earth MySQL requires an additional parameter,
    #        is well beyond my understanding...
    if uri.startswith('mysql'):
        if '?' in uri:
            uri += '&'
        else:
            uri += '?'
        uri += 'charset=%s' % encoding

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(uri, echo=debug)

    ......
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've hardcoded 'latin1' encoding like this: `def setConnection(uri, tables, encoding='latin1', debug=False):
    """Set connection for every table."""
    params = {'encoding': encoding}
    # FIXME: why on earth MySQL requires an additional parameter,
    #        is well beyond my understanding...
    if uri.startswith('mysql'):
        if '?' in uri:
            uri += '&'
        else:
            uri += '?'`And it seems to be working now! I had to downgrade [SQLAlchemy to version 1.4](https://github.com/cinemagoer/cinemagoer/issues/454) too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to wrap the **-u** argument in quotes?

Comment: Won't work. If I pass python3 imdbpy2sql.py -d `/home/username/frozendata -u 'mysql://imdb:imdb@host/imdb'`nothing changes. If I pass `python3 imdbpy2sql.py -d /home/username/frozendata -u \`mysql://imdb:imdb@localhost/imdb\`` I get `-bash: mysql://imdb:imdb@host/imdb`: No such file or directory Troubles with arguments.

Comment: maybe it's this answer with triple slashes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910847/cant-access-the-sql-database

Comment: Still the same issue occurs. Seems like the problem is with the "encoding" argument that script passes to SQLAlchemy function. I will try to hardcode [new MySQL-specific encoding 'utf8mb4'](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#charset-selection) into the script and see what happens.